# Limiting number of unique dates selected in SQLite3 SELECT Query

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

So basically, this is a SQLite3 table that I have:
[Click Here for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dsxl0.png)

As you can see in the image, there are 8 distinct dates, going from 29/07/2021 to 05/08/2021. I want to run a SQLite3 Query that returns only the latest 7 out of these 8 dates (i.e. 30/07/2021 to 05/08/2021) BUT it returns all the rows for each date.

I have tried using the LIMIT keyword like this:

```
all_app_data = sorted(conn.execute('SELECT date, application, usage_time FROM monitor '
                                   'ORDER BY date DESC, usage_time ASC LIMIT 7').fetchall())
```

However, this only picks up 1 row from each date (i.e. 1 row from 30/07/2021 instead of the 5 rows present). How can I fix this?

Comment: Create a query which finds the oldest of the seven newest dates and use it as subquery in "where" clause so that older dates are filtered out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `DENSE_RANK()` window function:

```
SELECT date, application, usage_time 
FROM (
  SELECT *, DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY date DESC) rn
  FROM monitor
) 
WHERE rn <= 7
ORDER BY date DESC, usage_time ASC
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you! Do you mind explaining what exactly is happening in this code, as I'm unaware of what the DENSE_RANK() function, OVER method, and the keyword 'rn' do.

Comment: @Angad_K DENSE_RANK() is a window function and it returns a number which is the rank of each row based on the ORDER BY clause inside OVER (). You can find more about it here: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/sqlite-dense_rank/

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by collecting the eligible dates in a subquery:

```sql
SELECT m1.date, m1.application, m1.usage_time 
FROM monitor m1 
WHERE m1.date IN
  (SELECT DISTINCT m2.date 
   FROM monitor m2
   ORDER BY m2.date DESC LIMIT 7)
ORDER BY m1.date DESC, m1.usage_time ASC
```

(You could also join against the subquery)